# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Entry'

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, typeerror

I am a new programmer, so please go easy on me.I am trying to take the Entry from the user and transform it into an int and then run the while loop. When I try to run this code on the while loop (line 13) I get this error code:
  Exception has occurred: TypeError
  '>' not supported between instances of 'IntVar' and 'IntVar'

My code:

```
import smtplib
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
AMNT_REPEAT= Entry(window, width=35, bg="white")
AMNT_REPEAT.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=W)

AMNT_REPEAT = IntVar()
x = 0

x = IntVar()

while AMNT_REPEAT > x :
    def click():
        global YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS , YOUR_PASSWORD , AMNT_REPEAT , 
TARGET_EMAIL , subject , msg
        YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS=YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS.get()
        YOUR_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD.get()
        TARGET_EMAIL=TARGET_EMAIL.get()
        subject=subject.get()
        msg=msg.get()
        AMNT_REPEAT=AMNT_REPEAT.get()

        send_email(subject, msg)

    AMNT_REPEAT = AMNT_REPEAT -1
```

Comment: `int(AMNT_REPEAT.get())`.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve]. As an aside, `import *` is generally bad practice.

Comment: @acw1668 this is what i get: can only concatenate str (not "Entry") to str

Comment: @AMC i updated the question and cut out as much text as I could. Also, what would you suggest I do instead of from tkinter import* ?

Comment: @NikolaJakovljevic _Also, what would you suggest I do instead of from tkinter import* ?_ While the ideal solution does depend on how much of the module you're using and how, just `import tkinter as tk` should be fine. I forgot to mention, using a bare except like that is bad practice, see .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except

Comment: Which line is causing the error '_can only concatenate str(not "Entry") to str_'?  BTW you should modify the line `AMNT_REPEAT = AMNT_REPEAT.get` inside `click()` because it will change `AMNT_REPEAT` to a function reference.

Comment: @AMC ok I think I made some progress and this is the new problem